# An n×n matrix B is define e^B by e^B=∑(B^j/j!) . Let P be the char polynomial of B.then the matrix e^P(B) is

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

An $n \times n$ matrix $B$ defines $e^B$ by $e^B=\sum\left(B^j/j!\right)$. Let $P$ be the char polynomial of $B$. Then the matrix $e^{P(B)}$ is

1. $I(n \times n)$
2. $O(n \times n)$
3. $eI(n \times n)$
4. $πI(n \times n)$

Comment: The options are on the body of the question

Comment: What is thar? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry its charecteristic poly

Comment: You can explicitly say what $P(B)$ is. What's your definition of characteristic polynomial? Or what basic facts do you know about it?

Answer (score -1):

By the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), every matrix satisfies it's own characteristic polynomial.  Thus

$P(B) = 0; \tag 1$

it follows that

$e^{P(B)} = e^0 = I. \tag 2$